# Python re.findall() to get all matched groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

This is delimited text but I want to parse it w/ regex.

Second column and next take seconds or milliseconds.

```
>>> import re 
>>> s = '''aaa
bbb|30s
ccc|500ms|1s'''
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:\|(\d+(?:s|ms)))?(?:\|(\d+(?:s|ms)))?', s)
```

Output(Expected answer):

```
[('aaa', '', ''), ('bbb', '30s', ''), ('ccc', '500ms', '1s')]
```

I wanted to make this pattern shorter by using quanti­fiers like * or {x,y}.

So I did:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:(?:\|(\d+(?:s|ms)))*)', cmdstr)

[('aaa', ''), ('bbb', '30s'), ('ccc', '500ms')]  # WRONG
```

I failed.

How can I do this regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking about whether you can use variable number of regex groups. Based on a quick Google search, the answer appears to be no, the regex will match the full pattern but only the last value will be recorded for repeated matches of the same group.

Consider simply doing `s.split('|')` and then whatever checks that are necessary on each of the substrings instead.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re 

s = '''aaa
bbb|30s
ccc|500ms|1s'''

print(re.findall(r'(\w+)\|?(\w+)?\|?(\w+)?', s))
```

Output:

```
[('aaa', '', ''), ('bbb', '30s', ''), ('ccc', '500ms', '1s')]
```